# ORDER BY CASE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I've got this annoying problem in SQL Server where I try to add a `ORDER BY @sortColumn`.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_get_checklist_activity]
(
     @userId int,
     @sortColumn varchar
)
[...]
SELECT
    checklist.checklist_id,
    [etc]
[... SQL BLA BLA ...] 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @sortColumn = 'checklist_id' 
      THEN checklist.checklist_id END,
    CASE WHEN @sortColumn = 'percentage' 
      THEN checklist.afgerond_percentage END,
    CASE WHEN @sortColumn = 'aangemaakt_op' 
      THEN checklist.aangemaakt_op END;
```

Now when I try to run it with something like:

```
[dbo].[pr_get_checklist_activity] 19, 'percentage'
```

or

```
[dbo].[pr_get_checklist_activity] 19, 'aangemaakt_op'
```

Nothing really happens, the results are the same. No error, no change...

I am building it as a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio and using VB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script works just fine. Everything seems ok, except 1 little thing:

```
@sortColumn varchar
```

this will make @sortColumn 1 character long. Put a length on it

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_get_checklist_activity]
(
 @userId int,
 @sortColumn varchar(40)

) as
```

This will fix your script

Answer (score 1):

Your `Order By` clause should probably be this:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE 
WHEN @sortColumn = 'checklist_id' THEN checklist.checklist_id
WHEN @sortColumn = 'percentage' THEN checklist.afgerond_percentage
WHEN @sortColumn = 'aangemaakt_op' THEN checklist.aangemaakt_op 
END;
```

Also you should define a length for your parameter `@sortColumn`. IIRC SQL Server will only assign that a length of 1.

So you stored proc definition should be :

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_get_checklist_activity]
(
 @userId int,
 @sortColumn varchar(50)

)
```

Comment: You missed to remove a comma at the end of the second when line.

Comment: First part of your answer will only work if the 3 columns has same type. Try it with varchar, date and integer. The posted question's syntax works better